# Give a user admin right to run yum on centos 8

Tags: centos, yum, administration, usermod

I give a user admin access with: `usermod -a -G wheel userX`
but when I log in with userX, I am not able to run `yum`. What do I need to do?
Thanks

Comment: Did you mean "sudo yum"?

Comment: You realise, if you want to grant a user the right to run yum, you might give him the right to full root instead? (Reason: if you can install arbitrary stuff and replace existing binaries with those of your choice, you can grant full root anyway). You might miss the sticky sudo bit

Comment: the user must have right to install packages with yum

Comment: Humm, I thought `dnf` had "replaced" `yum` on RHEL 8.   Yes, both are there under `/usr/bin` (AFAIR as symbolic links to `dnf-3`)  but `dnf` is now the "official' tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the wheel group commented out in `/etc/sudoers`? In the event that it is, the enrollment for `userX` in `wheel` will make no difference.

That being said, you don't have to enroll this user in `wheel` if you just want them to install packages via `sudo yum`. Just give that user the specific permission in `/etc/sudoers`:

`userX ALL = NOPASSWD : /usr/bin/yum, /bin/rpm`

userX would now be able to `sudo yum install whatever`, `sudo rpm -i whatever` (passwordless) but would be unable to run any other commands. You could remove them from the wheel group if you do this and have a more secure host. This depends on how much you trust this user and if you're comfortable enabling this functionality for them. Everything is a security risk, no matter which path you choose, so be sure you're wary of who you're adding.

Comment: I tried to create a devops user and added it to the sudoers file for installing packages but had no luck. I got this error: error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied). The idea is to have a controlled non root user with keys that can distribute and install software updates.